# How to make as many as possible https requests simultaneously and efficiently in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, http, asynchronous

I have multiple https requests. However, I have to wait sometime, say 1 minute, before response to come. I want to make http requests as many as possible simultaneously. I have tried thread pool but it causes too many threads in that I have many processes to run. Also, I tried [apache HttpAsyncClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/), but it didn't satisfy my requirement efficiently. It there any efficiently way to do that?

Comment: Have you considered netty?

Comment: What kind of ThreadPool? You know, there is "[FixedThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int))" that has a fixed number threads running simultaneously.

Comment: I have tried FixedThreadPoolExecutor.  However, I have at least ten  http requests type, and each kind  of request is made concurrently. Assume that I have 10 threads each threadpool and have 10 kinds of request at the same time. There will be 100 threads. In addition, I have monitor threads  etc.